# What can cause the JVM to fail to resolve DNS under load?

Tags: java, linux, load, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel

I'm investigating an issue with our service, which fails to resolve s3 bucket names under load.

I'm stressing a single c1.medium ec2 instance:

```
root@ip-10-243-126-111:/mnt/log# uname -a
Linux ip-10-243-126-111 2.6.35-30-virtual #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 11 23:41:40 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
root@ip-10-243-126-111:/mnt/log# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.10 \n \l
root@ip-10-243-126-111:/mnt/log# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1746008    1681752      64256          0      29600    1582508
-/+ buffers/cache:      69644    1676364
Swap:       917500         32     917468
```

The application is running with `-server,  jvm build 1.6.0_23-b05,  32bit`

The behaviour I'm seeing is network communications are starting to "act funny", sometimes socket timeout occur from our mongo connection driver, which looks like:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:35) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:35) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:110) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:75) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:201) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.5.3.jar:na]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

and at times the following happens

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bucket-system.s3.amazonaws.com
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:130) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732) ~[httpclient-4.1.jar:4.1]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:240) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.2.5.jar:na]
        ... 48 common frames omitted
```

This is reproducible but not consistent. Once load starts on the machine (50 concurrent http requests) the machines goes between cycles of responding correctly for ~5min then failing all requests for ~10sec then another cycle of correct responses.

What can cause such behavior? Is there any ulimit or other system setting I might try to tune to improve on this? Any more pointer to search for clues?

Another option I'm suspecting is the infrastructure at Amazon (us-east-1 region), I'm suspecting that the routers there active some kind of DoS prevention policy on the service because requests jump almost instantly from 0 to 50. After some time it stabilizes on a steady 50 concurrent rate at which point the hardware adjusts to the new traffic. Far fetched? I haven't found any mentions of this type of pattern anywhere.

Comment: Could you check the value `networkaddress.cache.ttl` in your java.security policy file?  The defaults are to cache the results of a name service lookup forever, but if the value is 300 (=5 min), then that might be an explanation for your cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to just DoS the amazon DNS servers.
Cache the IP of the host you're trying to reach and periodically update the cache. This will also increase overall performance of the application

Update: 
from the trace it's visible that the DNS host is just not responding to your requests. If you were to reach a ulimit, you would be faced with another Exception (something like unable to create socket).

Comment: Thanks Funtik but as you can see this also occurs with other servers like our mongo cluster or with another stuff that are meant to be scalable like CloudFront. Caching is besides the point here because what sends the actual request is aws-java-sdk S3 client.

Comment: Haven't worked with amazon that much, but I'd still try to cache this or isolate it in a separate service, which will not spawn a new DNS request for each client.
Does Mongo driver crash at the same time as aws java?

Comment: @Maxim Veksler: I am facing similar issue in my production environment. Were you able to find the root cause and resolution for your problem. Can you please share it. Thanks,Ashish

Comment: @user1270392 I am no longer employed at the relevant position but I believe that we ended up using Guava expiring cache to store the IP address for a number of milliseconds. That alleviated all the related DNS resolving issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maxim...If I understand it correctly, this means that you guys were probably not able to find the root cause. I mean was it related to DNS server itself or there was something not optimally done in code/configuration? Adding the caching using guava sounds goo, but doesn't that mean that we are hardcoding the ip-addresses in our code? One thing I tried though is that adding the hostname-IP in /etc/hosts and that solved the issue. However to me that also is not great, as the potentially the ip address can change.

Answer (score 3):

Are you simply running out of file descriptors? The first stack trace doesn't look anything DNS-specific.

What does ulimit -n say?
Does the problem go away if you give your process a (much) higher open file descriptor limit?

(Open / half-closed sockets consume file descriptors).

Comment: Thanks, this was the cause of my UnknownHostExceptions.  Increasing the open file limits fixed things.